# Prove $2^{n+3}|(p^2-1)$

Tags: number-theory

**Olympiad problem:**

> let odd prime nunmber $p$ such $$p|(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^n}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{2^n}$$
>   show that:
>   $$2^{n+3}|(p^2-1)$$

I want to take advantage of this conclusion：

if prime factor $ p $ of a Fermat number $ 2^{2^n} + 1 $ ,then  $ p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{n + 2}} $

But I failed

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If we set $ a_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n $ we have $a_0=2$, $a_1=4$ and
$$ a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1}-a_{n}, $$
$$ a_{2n} = a_n^2-2\tag{1}$$
Assuming that an odd prime $p$ is a divisor of $a_{2n}$, from $(1)$ it follows that $2$ is  a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$, hence $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$. In the general case, assume that $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $a_{2^n}$ and let $\xi\in\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(x^2-4x+1)$ be a root of $x^2-4x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. We have
$$ \xi^{2^n}=-\xi^{-2^n},\quad \xi^{2^{n+1}}=-1,\quad \xi^{2^{n+2}}=1\tag{2}$$
hence the order of $\xi$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$ is $2^{n+2}$ and by Lagrange's theorem $2^{n+2}\mid (p^2-1)$.
You just have to gain an extra $2$ factor: for such a purpose, prove that $\xi$ itself is a square.

Comment: That extra factor 2 comes from the fact that $\xi$ is itself a square in $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$. This is obvious, if $\xi\in\Bbb{F}_p$. Otherwise $x^2-4x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$. The other zero of that polynomial is $1/\xi=\xi^p$ (by Frobenius automorphism), and therefore $\xi^{p+1}=1$. So $\xi$ belongs to the unique subgroup of order $p+1$ inside $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*$. Cyclicity of the latter group then implies that $\xi=\eta^{p-1}$ for  some $\eta\in\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*$. Because $p-1$ is even, we see that the order of $\eta^{(p-1)/2}$ is $2^{n+3}$.

Comment: +1, of course. This is more or less how I had started working on the question, when your answer came :-)

Comment: Thanks,I think some students can't understand ,because this is olympiad problem\

Comment: I believe you mean that $2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @robjohn: silly typo, sure. Thanks.

Comment: I hope see middle school sutudent can understand methods,because it's a  olympaid problem

Answer (score 2):

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+2}}$, then either $p\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+3}}$ or $p\equiv 2^{n+2}+1\pmod{2^{n+3}}$. In either case, squaring yields $p^2\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+3}}$.

Comment: first,Thank you for answer,and I have some problem, How to use this conclusion?on the  other words,How to problem my problem is equivalent $p|2^{2^n}+1$,Thanks